# TabNavigator - Hide status bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-native and react-navigation.

I want to hide the status bar. But it's either remains visible, or it is not working the way I try to hide it.

First attempt leads to a complete white screen. As if the navigator isn't even loaded.
Same thing for second attempt.
Last attempt is working, i have what i want but status bar is displayed. I want it hidden.

Example i found on the web were working with the same syntax as my second attempt. I don't understand why mine isn't working..

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar, View } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import PageLecture from './js/PageLecture';
import PageSalat from './js/PageSalat';
import PageHadiths from './js/PageHadiths';
import PageParametres from './js/PageParametres';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // This is not working
        // return (
        //     <View>
        //         <View>
        //             <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
        //         </View>
        //
        //         <ReactCoran />
        //     </View>
        // );

        // This is not working
        // return (
        //     <View>
        //         <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
        //         <ReactCoran />
        //     </View>
        // );

        // This is working but status bar is displayed
        return (
            <ReactCoran />
        );
    }
}


const ReactCoran = TabNavigator({
    Lecture: {
        screen: PageLecture,
    },
    Salat: {
        screen: PageSalat,
    },
    Hadith: {
        screen: PageHadiths,
    },
    Parametres: {
        screen: PageParametres,
    }
},
{
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    tabBarOptions: {
        allowFontScaling: true,
        activeTintColor: '#000000',
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        activeBackgroundColor: '#ff0000',
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#aa0000',
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
            height:2,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        }
    },
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how `ReactCoran` is implemented, but this usually works:

Add `style={{flex: 1}}` to parent view

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'

<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
    <ReactCoran />
</View>
```

Let me know if this helps. If not show us code of `ReactCoran`.

Answer (score 1):

There are below three methods to remove :

1. First Method

   ```
   <Stack.Navigator
   initialRouteName="HomeActivity"
   screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
   >
   <Stack.Screen>
   .......
   </Stack.Screen>
   </Stack.Navigator>
   ```
2. Method

   ```
   React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
   navigation.setOptions({headerShown: false});
    }, [navigation]);
   ```
3. Method you are using in your code

If it doesn't work please provide some more details , because if you don't want to use Status bar then there is no use to    you can simple choose 1st method.

Answer (score -1):

In react-navigation the status bar can be hidden by adding:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
```

to the component. More info here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator

Comment: This hides the header but it doesn't hide the status bar.

Comment: `header: null` is to hide the Header bar not the StatusBar